# Cobweb category utility

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, clustering

I'm trying to understand the category utility function in the COBWEB algorithm.

Assume you have the following data and build a set C of three clusters (three child-nodes under the root node), one for `amphibian` (C1), one for `fish` (C2) and one for `bird/mammal` (C3).

[image]

[image]

Using the above CU formula, I'm now trying to compute the total category utility like this.

P(C1) = **0.25**, P(C2) = **0.25**, P(C3) = **0.5**

P(body_cover=moist_skin) = P(body_cover=scales) = P(body_cover=feathers) = P(body_cover=hair) = P(heart_chamber=3) = P(heart_chamber=2) = **0.25**

P(body_temp=unregulated) = P(body_temp=regulated) = P(fertilisation=external) = P(fertilisation=internal) = P(heart_chamber=4) = **0.5**

CU_C1 = 0.25 * ((1²-0.25²) + (1²-0.25²) + ((1²-0.5²) + (1²-0.5²)) = **0.84375**

CU_C2 = 0.25 * ((1²-0.25²) + (1²-0.25²) + ((1²-0.5²) + (1²-0.5²)) = **0.84375**

CU_C3 = 0.5 * ((0.5²-0.25²) + (0.5²-0.25²) + (1²-0.5²) + ((1²-0.5²) + (1²-0.5²)) = **1.3125**

Or generally:

```
CU_C3 = P(C3) * (
    (P(body_cover=feathers|C3) - P(body_cover=feathers)) + 
    (P(body_cover=hair|C3) - P(body_cover=hair)) + 
    (P(heart_chamber=4|C3) - P(heart_chamber=4)) + 
    (P(fertilisation=internal|C3) - P(fertilisation=internal))
)
```

CU = (CU_C1 + CU_C2 + CU_C3) / |C| = (0.84375 + 0.84375 + 1.3125) / 3 = **1**

**I'd like to know if my computations are correct** and if 1 is actually the final CU value for that partitioning. Can you help me?

I also found the following solution, but I can't reproduce it. In my understanding the two inner loops / sums are iterating over the attribute and each attribute's value, regardless of the datapoints contained in the cluster.

CU_C3 = 0.5 * (((0.5² - 0.25²) + (1² - 0.5²) + (1² - 0.5²) + (1² - 0.5²))
+ ((0.5² - 0.25²) + (1² - 0.5²) + (1² - 0.5²) + (1² - 0.52²)) = **2.4273**

... leading to CU = **1.375**

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure anybody here will check your calculations. Are you not sure about the *formula* or about what happens when you substitute numbers into it? Or perhaps you're unsure about some of the numbers you plug in?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to check soem calculations, not a question.